# matplotlib.pyplot.plotの最大値について

Tags: python, matplotlib

掲記メソッドによりグラフを表示させようと思っているのですが、デフォルトだとグラフが小さいので、pyplot.figure(figsize= )によりグラフサイズを大きくしました。

しかしながら、ある程度までは大きくなるものの、それ以上にはなりません。（例えば、figsize = (10000,10000)などとしても、ばかでかくなるわけではないです）

これは、figsizeに指定できる数値に上限があるためでしょうか。あるいは、何か指定の仕方が悪いだけで、ばかでかくする方法はあるのでしょうか。

更には、subplotsにより複数のグラフを表示させるときにも、figsizeをある程度大きく指定したいと思っているのですが同様に一定以上にはならないことについてもご教示賜りたいと存じます。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく、デフォルトではデスクトップスクリーンのピクセルサイズを100で割った値が最大値です。(あるいは縦はそれから上下のタイトルバー/ツールバーサイズを引いた分)

例えばフルHDの画面ならば`pyplot.figure(figsize=(19.20, 10.80))`でしょう。

マルチモニタで拡張画面にしていれば、その拡張した画面の最大値までです。

ただし、描画処理に使うモジュール(TkinterとかQtとかwxなど)の機能に依存するようなので、論理的な画面を実際のモニタ環境よりも大きく取れるモジュール(あるいはそのための設定)が使えれば、それに応じて拡大可能かもしれません。

Windows10のPython 3.7.4 Tkinterでは、デスクトップスクリーンよりも大きなサイズを指定した場合は、デスクトップスクリーンのサイズに調整されるか、あるいは例外になっていました。

どういう値から例外になるかの境界までは調べていません。

参考にしたのは以下です。
[matplotlib逆引きメモ（フレーム編）](https://qiita.com/cnloni/items/20b5908fbae755192498)

> [1-7. ディスプレイ上に描画される図のサイズを知りたい](https://qiita.com/cnloni/items/20b5908fbae755192498#1-7-%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%AB%E6%8F%8F%E7%94%BB%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E5%9B%B3%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA%E3%82%92%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%8A%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)
>   バージョン2.0以降のデフォルト値は、ピクセル単位で640x480です（図1の赤点枠のサイズ）。
>   [image: Figure1-1]
>
> [1-8. 図のサイズを指定したい](https://qiita.com/cnloni/items/20b5908fbae755192498#1-8-%E5%9B%B3%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA%E3%82%92%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)
>   例えば、横幅を800ピクセル、高さを600ピクセルにしたい場合、リスト1-2のように2段階でインスタンスを作成します。
>
> ```
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>
> fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.0, 6.0))
> ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
> plt.show()
> ```
>
> [1-10. figsizeキーワードの意味は？](https://qiita.com/cnloni/items/20b5908fbae755192498#1-9-pltfigure%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%82%92%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE)
>   figsizeキーワードを使って、図の横幅と高さ（図1の赤点枠）をインチ単位で指定することができます。タプルで指定します。指定しなかった場合は、デフォルト値の(6.4, 4.8)が採用されます。
>
> [1-11. インチ単位とピクセル単位の関係は？](https://qiita.com/cnloni/items/20b5908fbae755192498#1-11-%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E5%8D%98%E4%BD%8D%E3%81%A8%E3%83%94%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%AB%E5%8D%98%E4%BD%8D%E3%81%AE%E9%96%A2%E4%BF%82%E3%81%AF)
>   インチ単位をピクセル単位にするにはdpiパラメータの値が必要ですが、dpiのデフォルト値は100です。リスト1-2の例なら、横幅 = 8.0x100 = 800ピクセル、高さ = 6.0x100 = 600ピクセルになります。
>
> [1-14. デフォルト値を知りたい](https://qiita.com/cnloni/items/20b5908fbae755192498#1-14-%E3%83%87%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%88%E5%80%A4%E3%82%92%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%8A%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)
>       import matplotlib as mpl
>
> ```
> print(mpl.matplotlib_fname())
> ```
>
> matplotlibでは、各種のパラメータのデフォルト値が定められています。システムに最初から格納されているファイルのパスは、リスト1-6のように、matplotlib_fnameで知ることができます。デフォルト値を示すファイルは、matplotlibrcという名前です。
>
> このファイルの一部をリスト1-7に示します。上に述べたように、figsizeのデフォルト値は(6.4, 4.8)、dpiのデフォルト値が100になっていることが分かります。システムのmatplotlibrcでは、backend以外のパラメータが全てコメントアウトされています。変更する場合は、当該行をアンコメントして、値を変更します。
>
> ```
> #figure.figsize   : 6.4, 4.8   ## figure size in inches
> #figure.dpi       : 100        ## figure dots per inch
> ```

---

[matplotlib.pyplot.figure](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html)

---

他に、複数グラフ作成の考え方の参考記事

[matplotlib基礎 | figureやaxesでのグラフのレイアウト](https://qiita.com/tsuruokax/items/90167693f142ebb55a7d)
[matplotlib の figure（図） と axes（座標軸）－python](http://ailaby.com/matplotlib_fig/)
[早く知っておきたかったmatplotlibの基礎知識、あるいは見た目の調整が捗るArtistの話](https://qiita.com/skotaro/items/08dc0b8c5704c94eafb9)